# How to return a result with duplicate id using whereIn in AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js, lucid

I have a list of IDs and I want to query the database.

I press that it returns in order of index the data that appears in the list of Id.

I intend to return a list compatible with the same ID's duplicated and in order.

Is there how?

Thanks for listening

```
 const result = await Estoque.query().preload('armazem').whereIn('siaId',  ['1122', '4455', '55664', '1122', '008', '4455']).orderBy('validade', 'asc')
```

Expected outcome

```
[
{siaId:'1122', ...},
{siaId:'4455', ...},
{siaId:'55664', ...},
{siaId:'1122', ...},
{siaId:'008', ...},
{siaId:'4455', ...}
]
```

Updated

How to convert this to lucid Adonis?

```
SELECT *
FROM estoques
JOIN ( -- This is your "IN" list
          SELECT '1122' AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT '4455' AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT '55664' AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT '1122' AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT '008' AS ID
UNION ALL SELECT '4455' AS ID
) x ON x.ID = estoques.siaId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

```
const result = await Estoque.query().whereNull('siaId').union( (query)=> {
      _.forEach(_.flatten(cods), async (v, i)=>{
        if(i<=2) {
          query.from('estoques').whereNull('sia_id').unionAll(Database.from('estoques').where('sia_id', v))
        }
        })
    }, true).preload('armazem').orderBy('validade', 'asc')
```